# Create a dynamic Text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to do a program with javascript and html believes me a text file using dynamic variables, the problem is, I can't do the dinamic variables to do more faster the process.

```
function obtenerDatos() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
        return {
            var v = [];

            for (i; i < 14; i++) {
                v[i]: document.getElementById(i).value
            };


            //eval("v"+i): document.getElementById(i);


            /*v1: document.getElementById('1').value,
                        v2: document.getElementById('2').value,
                        v3: document.getElementById('3').value,
                        v4: document.getElementById('4').value,
                        v5: document.getElementById('5').value,
                        v6: document.getElementById('6').value,
                        v7: document.getElementById('7').value,
                        v8: document.getElementById('8').value,
                        v9: document.getElementById('9').value,
                        v10: document.getElementById('10').value,
                        v11: document.getElementById('11').value,
                        v12: document.getElementById('12').value,
                        v13: document.getElementById('13').value,
                        v14: document.getElementById('14').value,
                        fecha: (new Date()).toLocaleDateString()*/
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: `v[i]: document.getElementById(i).value` is **not** a valid JavaScript. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `i` in an number... it can't be an id...

Comment: Are you trying to assign these elements to variables named `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, etc? If so, that's the wrong way of solving this. You have an array, you should be adding values to it. You do this via assignment, with the `=` operator: `v[i] = document.getElementById(i).value`. You need to choose real IDs though.

Comment: Please explain what you want in more detail.